# Error while publishing asp.net MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to publish mvc 3 application and 
I had followed below instruction

> http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

but I got following error

```
Attempt by method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.get_GlobalAsaxTypeName()' to access method 'System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxType()' failed.
```

and full error stack is:

```
[MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.get_GlobalAsaxTypeName()' to access method 'System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetGlobalAsaxType()' failed.]
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.get_GlobalAsaxTypeName() +47
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.PostProcessGeneratedCode(CodeCompileUnit codeCompileUnit, CodeNamespace generatedNamespace, CodeTypeDeclaration generatedClass, CodeMemberMethod executeMethod) +205
   System.Web.Razor.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCodeCore(LookaheadTextReader input, String className, String rootNamespace, String sourceFileName, Nullable`1 cancelToken) +343
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode() +253
   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +37
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +65
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +218
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +40
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +8919802
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +320
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +111
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +125
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath) +41
   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations) +274
   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache) +130
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindView>b__b(IViewEngine e) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths) +132
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName) +183
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +90
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +329
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +31
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8771193
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

seems, trying to access private member/function , but this is running on my local. I had install .net 4.0 on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on full of abstraction till yet, although I got solution by downloading .net framework 4.0 and install it. may I was using old .net framework.